# Custom Post Type Permalink with Custom Taxonomy And Duplicate Post Names and Slugs

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create different communities, each with their own set of pages (About, Services, etc). The permalink structure I currently have set up is sitename.com/community/state/city/parent-page-name/
The city and state are being pulled from a location custom taxonomy with the cities being children under the states.
If I wanted to have an about page for a community named The Oaks in Topeka, Kansas, then the url would be:
sitename.com/community/ks/topeka/the-oaks/about
However, when I try to create multiple communities with many different about pages, all of the about pages default to the same about page for the first community that was published.

My custom post type looks like this:

```
function community_post_type() {
    $singular = 'Community';
    $plural = 'Communities';
    register_post_type('community',
        array(
         'labels' => array(
            'name' => __($plural, 'base'),
            'singular_name' => __($singular, 'base'),
            'all_items' => __('All ' . $plural, 'base'),
            'add_new' => __('Add New ' . $singular, 'base'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New ' . $singular, 'base'),
            'edit' => __('Edit ' . $singular, 'base'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit ' . $singular, 'base'),
            'new_item' => __('New ' . $singular, 'base'),
            'view_item' => __('View ' . $singular, 'base'),
            'search_items' => __('Search ' . $plural, 'base'),
            'not_found' => __('Nothing found in the Database.', 'base'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash', 'base'),
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Main Community',
        ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => __('This is the ' . $singular . ' post type', 'base'),
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-location-alt',
        'has_archive' => true,        
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes', 'custom-fields'),
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'menu_position' =>  4,
        'taxonomies'  => array( 'location' ),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'community/%comm%'),
        )
    );
}
```

And here is my code to change the permalinks:

```
function change_permalinks( $post_link, $id = 0){
    $post = get_post($id);  
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'community' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'location' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '%comm%' , $terms[0]->slug .'/'. $terms[1]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;  
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'change_permalinks', 1, 3 );

function generated_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^community/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=community&name=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'generated_rewrite_rules' );
```

If I use about1, about2, about3, etc as the page slugs then it works fine, but I can't use the same slug or else it just goes to the same page for each of the 700 locations.

Comment: why dont you use in ur rewrite rule another parameter to capture so wordpress knows what term its related to?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What would that look like?

Comment: Some additional information - it is showing the correct URL for each of the pages, but it displays the content and post id from the page that was last updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this list of available query vars to adapt your url to receive any post as desired

https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars

I imagine for your case it could look something like this, I have not tested it but its a hint for you to go by

```
function generated_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^community/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=community&taxonomy=location&term=$matches[1]&name=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'generated_rewrite_rules' );
```

this will tell wordpress to get the post with a taxonomy location and with a certain state from the first match.

You can of course tweak this to match your result more accurately or use thoose query_vars in your post template file to build your arguments for *get_post/WP_Query* more correctly so to speak, an example of how that might look can be found here

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters

I would also recommend if its not working as desired hook into [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) print out the query and check how it looks for further debugging

Example:

```
function check_query_vars( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin()) {
        // Not a query for an admin page.
    //print the queried variables or if you like to see EVERYTHING dump $query
        print_r($query->query_vars);
   
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'check_query_vars' );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. I'm wondering if it has more to do with the rewrite when I'm registering the post type. I have the rewrite using %comm%, which then uses a str_replace in an additional function, but when I am creating the post, it just says /community/%comm%/about. So, essentially all the posts are named /community/%comm%/about, which may be why they are all redirecting to the same post.

Comment: @kfww-dev updated my post to help you further debugging your issue

Comment: It shows the correct community in the query vars, but the wrong content is being displayed.

Comment: @kfww-dev why dont you post what the returned data looks like to your question and I might be able to help you from there